# googleapis package - oAuth2 get token returns [invalid_grant bad request]

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication

I'm using the official google package (googleapis) in the latest version, but the result when it comes to getting the token is returning 400 bad request:

```
export const googleId = process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID;
export const googleSecret = process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET;
export const redirectUrl = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/login/auth`;

export const scope = [
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
];

export const googleAuthClient = new google.auth.OAuth2(
  googleId,
  googleSecret,
  redirectUrl
);
```

I have already made sure that the credentials are being loaded correctly from within the process.env.

```
async login(code: string): Promise<User> {
    const authUrl = this.generate();
    try {
      const {tokens} = await googleAuthClient.getToken(code);
      googleAuthClient.setCredentials(tokens);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
```

However, the above code is not working correctly.

After opening the login form, logging in and getting the **code** in the **redirect_url** (everything being generated correctly), I call the login function with the code and get the return:

```
  response: {
    config: {
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token',
      data: 'code=CODE_HERE&client_id=CLIENT_ID_HERE&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET_HERE&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URL_HERE&grant_type=authorization_code&code_verifier=',
      headers: [Object],
      paramsSerializer: [Function: paramsSerializer],
      validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
      responseType: 'json'
    },
    data: { error: 'invalid_grant', error_description: 'Bad Request' },
    headers: {
      'alt-svc': 'h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"',
      'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate',
      connection: 'close',
      'content-encoding': 'gzip',
      'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      date: 'Fri, 28 May 2021 18:44:07 GMT',
      expires: 'Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT',
      pragma: 'no-cache',
      server: 'scaffolding on HTTPServer2',
      'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
      vary: 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer',
      'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
      'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
      'x-xss-protection': '0'
    },
    status: 400,
    statusText: 'Bad Request',
    request: { responseURL: 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token' }
  },
```

Naturally I omitted the data in the answer, but they are correct.

Does anyone know what may be going on?

I already turned the internet upside down and found nothing.